# Sql Server. Sproc in Central Database denied read permission on Tables in Target Databases

Tags: sql-server

There is a central database which houses 'User' information. There are Target databases which are owned by 'Areas'. A user can conduct business in any of the target databases.

A sproc in the central database is being used to provide a transaction summary for the user.
It simply provides a union of DatabaseA and DatabaseB and ... records.

Works fine from SSMS but the calling code fails in the app because select permission is denied on the target Database tables.

I have tried creating new users with dbo rights  representing NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER and xxxxx\sql-service in a target database but still get the permission error.

What is the correct way to handle this situation? (I have full control over the security of the databases)

thanks

Comment: What login do you use when it fails as opposed to when it works? Does this login have permissions to the actual tables?

Comment: I had missed one of the tables when assigning explicit select rights. Doesn't  seem a robust way of dealing with this. There will be new target databases in the future and someone will have to remember to assign the permissions. I have altered the ownership of the current databases so they are all owned by a common owner. Is 'cross database chaining'  the answer?

Comment: Yes, I guess you may use that if you have the same owners of the database.

Comment: OK. Thanks for your responses on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To recap the discussion in the comments:

1. You need to make sure you have permissions for all underlying tables in all databases for the login you're using.
2. You can use cross database chaining to make permission management easier if the owner af all databases and objects is the same.